# Automate deploying flutter web wiith Github Actions

Tags: flutter, github-actions, github-pages, flutter-web

When building flutter web app and deploying it to github pages peanut package is quite useful since it builds the project and and put it to a gh-pages branch.
Q. How would you automate all this with github actions.

```
name: Web CI

on:
 push:
   branches: [ "main" ]
 pull_request:
   branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
 build:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest

   steps:
   - uses: actions/checkout@v3
   - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
     with:
       flutter-version: '3.x'
       channel: 'stable'
   - run: flutter pub get
   - run: flutter pub global activate peanut
   - run: flutter pub global run peanut
```

Comment: This is a more concise solution that worked for me https://niemtec.com/deploying-a-flutter-web-app-to-github-pages/

Answer (score 0):

Get token with `public_repo, repo:status` from [settings](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and create a secret on repository to commit from setting and put

[image]

```yaml
name: deploy web on github-page
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build Web
    env:
      my_secret: ${{secrets.commit_secret}}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          channel: "stable"
      - run: flutter config --enable-web
      - run: flutter clean
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter build web --release --web-renderer html --base-href /yourRepositoryName/
      - run: |
          cd build/web
          git init
          git config --global user.email yourEmail.com
          git config --global user.name yourUsername
          git status
          git remote add origin https://${{secrets.commit_secret}}@github.com/yourUserName/repository.git
          git checkout -b gh-pages
          git add --all
          git commit -m "update"
          git push origin gh-pages -f
```

Comment: Sorry for a late response. I did try find another solution which is more concise so i didn't try this solution. The link to the alternate solution is https://niemtec.com/deploying-a-flutter-web-app-to-github-pages/